# Different remaining flag background colors?

Tags: discussion, support

When trying to flag something, the *remaining flags* count does not always have the same background color.

It is orange for posts and red for comments. I have the impression SO uses very specific colors to stealthily encourage specific behaviour.

Does coloring imply that comments should be flagged with more caution than posts? Or more rarely perhaps?

Here is the remaining flag count from the `flag` window, for questions :

[image: Question flag]

And for comments:

[image: Comment flag]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a mistake. Comment flags have no effect on your flagging abilities, whereas declined post flags can contribute to a temporary ban.

Comment: If it is a bug, then I suggest to create a bug report. If you are a programmer, you know, which type of bug reports you like at most - you also probably know, that not this. :-) Attach screenshots to that, attach concrete links, _where_ you found the bug, and go the the meta.stackexchange.com with them.

Comment: I was wondering the same right now. Because I had a few rejected flags I got a little afraid actually.